# Project is not compatible with uap10.0.16299 (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have created Xamarin project which is in .NET standard. Now I am trying to add .NET core 5.0 Class library reference in Xamarin project and i am getting below error. Any solution will be helpful.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error NU1201  Project Db.Models is not compatible with uap10.0.16299
> (UAP,Version=v10.0.16299) / win10-x86. Project Db.Models supports:
> net5.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v5.0)ui.UWP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolution for the issue. I converted all the

> .NET 5

libraries in

> .NET standard

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

> I have created Xamarin project which is in .NET standard. Now I am trying to add .NET core 5.0 Class library reference in Xamarin project

I'm afraid you can't refer .NET 5 class library for UWP platform. Creating UWP apps running on .NET 5 is not supported yet. Derive from Richard blog [Announcing .NET 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/) *The Windows team is working on Project Reunion as the next step forward for UWP and related technologies.*. Please pay attention to the .NET release [note](https://github.com/dotnet/core/tree/master/release-notes).